# PostgreSQL SQL Statement to generate custom blob storage table

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I need to use the awesome-looking [django-storages Database storage backend](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/database.html) for a current project, but:

> It can be used to map filenames to database blobs: so you have to use it with a special additional table created manually. The table should contain a pk-column for filenames (better to use the same type that FileField uses: nvarchar(100)), blob field (image type for example) and size field (bigint).

I'll admit it. ORM's have spoiled me. Its been a while since I've written an SQL statement, and I'm not at all familiar with PostgreSQL's flavor of SQL & BLOBs.

So, could someone pretty please help me out with a Postgres CREATE TABLE statement with three columns mentioned above (FILE_NAME, BLOB, FILE_SIZE), along with the appropriate column types?

Comment: If anyone's wondering.  I ended up not using Database storage backend because its basically incompatible with Postgresql, has licensing issues, and didn't give me a good impression.  I wrote my own custom storage backend that uses Text fields and base64 encoding as recommended here: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB, which is awesome. I'd be happy to share if you reach out to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You generally use a column of type [`bytea`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-binary.html) for blobs in PostgreSQL. Your statement could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE (
  file_name text PRIMARY KEY
 ,blob bytea
 ,file_size bigint
);
```

There is no `nvarchar` in PostgreSQL like in SQL Server. You could use `varchar(100)` but I would advise to just use [`text`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) without modifier instead.

There are other options to store blobs. Refer to this [related answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7439642/939860).