Pros and drawbacks of storing files as bytestrings versus blobs in Postgres
This is not a problem per se. I have small files of about 3-5 MB. I have the option to save them as either a blob in the DB of type bytea or read the file into a byte array, encode then save the resulting byte string.
Technically, a bytea is a binary string array and is almost, if not similar, to my approach, only that Postgres handles everything. Anyone tried this before? How was your experience?

It's not clear what you mean by "a byte array, encode then save the resulting byte string" - what would that encoding do and how is a "byte string" different from a "byte array"? What do you expect to gain from this extra processing?

For a file, I would use a file system, not a database. That also makes backups and potential restores easier.

Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7434530/939860

Always use bytea for binary data. That saves you the effort of encoding to and decoding from a string, and you won't waste any storage space.
